# Racket module contract confuse me

Tags: racket

the module: test-define.rkt

```
#lang racket

(provide test)

(provide (contract-out [add-test! (-> void)]))

(define test 0)

(define (add-test!)
  (set! test (add1 test)))
```

the main program:act.rkt

```
#lang racket

(require "test-define.rkt")

(printf "~a~%" test)

(add-test!)

(printf "~a~%" test)
```

run the act.rkt, I get:

```
0
1
```

this is what I want.

But if I change the contract in test-define.rkt:

```
(provide test)
```

change to

```
(provide (contract-out [test integer?]))
```

then I run the act.rkt again, I get:

```
0
0
```

Why? I can't change the test value.

If I provide a get func, it turns normal again.

```
(provide (contract-out [get-test (-> integer?)]))

(define (get-test)
  test)
```

If test's type change to hash map, it's always normal.

What I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice that in test-define.rkt you have this line

```
(set! test3 (add1 test))
```

Should `test3` be `test` ?

This might explain why you saw that two zeros (test never changed).

EDIT 2

For convenience I put your two modules in the same file
and changed the contract of test:

```
#lang racket
(module test-define racket 
  (provide test)
  ; (provide (contract-out [test integer?]))
  (provide get-test)
  (provide (contract-out [add-test! (-> void)]))
  (define test 0)
  (define (add-test!)
    (set! test (add1 test)))
  (define (get-test)
  test))

(module ack racket
  (require (submod ".." test-define))
  (printf "~a~%" test)
  (add-test!)
  (printf "~a~%" test))

(require (submod "." ack))
```

Now I see the 0 1 vs 0 0 output as you do.

Hmmm. Why?

Well. If we change the provide forms to use no contracts
at all, the output is 0 1.

Adding a contract shouldn't change this behaviour (I think).
Maybe a bug?

http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/guide/contracts-gotchas.html?q=contract&q=ignore

Says:

> The contract library assumes that variables exported via contract-out
>   are not assigned to, but does not enforce it. Accordingly, if you try
>   to set! those variables, you may be surprised. ...snip... Moral: This
>   is a bug that we will address in a future release.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is my first stackoverflow answer!But this is my type mistake, I fix it already.This problem confuse me, is some basic theory of racket's module or contract i don't gasp?

Comment: I can not run your ack.rkt as it is above. A definition of `get-test` is missing.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I mistype again. it should be:(printf "~a~%" test) and my racket version is 5.2.1. Thanks for your respones, I expected your answer.

Comment: Now my local time is 10:00 pm, what time is your place?Please don't leave, I will refresh page again and again.I'm happy see you return.

Comment: It is Tour de France time here :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, my first stackoverflow question is so great!